# Dont understand an example (ideal)

Tags: abstract-algebra

There is an example in my book i don't understand.

"Let I be the principal ideal (3) in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$. **Then the cosets of I are just the congruence classes modulo 3, and so there are three distinct cosets:**
$0 + I = [0]$, $1 + I = [1]$, $2 + I =[2]$. The set $\mathbb{Z}/I$ of all cosets is precisely the set $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

So as I understand it $ I = 3\mathbb{Z} = $ { $\dots, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, \dots$}
But from here it is just a mess. I have a hardtime understanding the part market with **xxxx**

Comment: I don't think I understand what exactly your question is...

Comment: I have edit. Sorry English is not my native language.

Answer (score 2):

Might it help to expand the other two cosets as follows?
$$[1] = 1 + 3\mathbb{Z} = \{n : n-1 \in I \} = \{ \ldots, -5, -2, 1, 4, 7, 10, \ldots\}$$
$$[2] = 2 + 3\mathbb{Z} = \{n: n-2 \in I\} = \{ \ldots, -4, -1, 2, 5, 8, 11, \ldots\}$$

At this point you see that the three cosets $[0], [1], [2]$ form a partition of $\mathbb{Z}$, and thus we have a complete description of the cosets.

Comment: So if u "add" all the cosets u will get back $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: if by add you mean "take the union of", then yes, see my elaboration above

Comment: Can I look at it this way. The ideal is some subset such that if $r \in R$ and $ i \in I$ then $ ri \in I$ and $ir \in I$. Given this subset then the cosets are all the sets that when you take the union of them, you get back $R$. Where the cosets are disjoint.

Comment: As long as you specify that cosets are sets of the form $x+I = \{x+i: i\in I\}$ for some $x\in R$.

Comment: Yes. thanks!  So if I would be the principal ideal (5) in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\mathbb{Z}/I$ would be the set $\mathbb{Z}_5$ ?

Comment: @ Olba12: Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The “nature” of objects has changed from numbers to (infinite) classes of numbers. When you deal with classes modulo 3, each class is an element  and you have 3 disjoint subsets (the elements  (0), (1), (2)) whose union is  Z. It is easily verified that 3Z= (0) is the  zero, (1), is the unit and that (2) is its own inverse in the (consequently) field of 3 elements. I hope this could give you a little help.